# Angular-Fullstack Requiring external module babel-register

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I am getting this error when use `gulp serve` from a angular-fullstack project generator. Please, how can I solve this issue? The dependencie was set in `package.json` properly.

```
[18:03:54] Requiring external module babel-register
/home/gcfabri/Workspace/sportfitness/gulpfile.babel.js:4
import _ from 'lodash';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at loader (/home/gcfabri/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:134:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/gcfabri/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/home/gcfabri/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/home/gcfabri/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:192:16)
```

Comment: have you run the npm install command in your folder?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to run `npm install --save babel-require`. You can read more about it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/).

**Edit:** Just to explain a bit better, the purpose of `babel-require` is to compile required packages with babel on the fly. In this case I'm assuming it's meant to be compiling ES6 javascript syntax back to ES5 syntax, because it's failing on the newer ES6 `import` syntax.

I'm not sure how babel ended up in your gulp pipeline there, but it's explicitly being required by something in `/home/gcfabri/Workspace/sportfitness/gulpfile.babel.js`. I wouldn't recommend removing it, but just so you have an idea of what's happening.

I hope installing that dependancy helps.