# Error with gulp serve: Requiring external module babel-register

Tags: gulp, yeoman, babeljs

Running yeoman generator "Webapp", I'm getting an error when running gulp serve. Here are the following versions for a better background :

```
sw_vers && node -e 'console.log(process.platform, process.versions)'
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.3
BuildVersion:   15D21
darwin { http_parser: '2.6.0',
  node: '5.2.0',
  v8: '4.6.85.31',
  uv: '1.7.5',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '47',
  openssl: '1.0.2e' }

node -v
v5.2.0

gulp -v
Requiring external module babel-register
CLI version 3.9.1
Local version 3.9.1
```

Finally the gulp serve error:

```
gulp serve
Requiring external module babel-register
\node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:372
      throw new Error("Couldn't find preset " + JSON.stringify(val) + "      relative to directory " + JSON.stringify(dirname));
```

Does anybody have any idea what the problem could be, any suggestions?

Here's what I've tried:

```
npm uninstall gulp 
npm install gulp 
//with global flag and not
npm install --save-dev gulp 
//installing babel-register manually w/wo global flag and --save-dev
npm install babel-register
npm cache clean
```

Also read through several of other posts with similar problem with no success, some of the following :

[gulp serve: Failed to load external module babel-core/register](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/356)

[Requiring external module babel/register #726](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/issues/726)

[babel was renamed to babel-core #727](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/pull/727)

[Angular-Fullstack Requiring external module babel-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349078/angular-fullstack-requiring-external-module-babel-register)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

yep, after running `npm install --global gulp-cli` I run `gulp -v` and I’ve got

```
Failed to load external module babel-register
Requiring external module babel-core/register
CLI version 1.2.1
Local version 3.9.1
```

then I updated CLI version to 3.9.1 (same as I have locally) but it did not help.
but when I **downgrade CLI version to 3.9.0** it started work correct and message “Failed to load external module babel-register” not shown anymore. 
Looks like 3.9.1 is buggy.
Run:

```
npm install -g gulp@3.9.0
```

hopefully it'll help you.

Comment: Wow.  That was it.

Comment: Thats the ONLY solution that worked for me, after searching deeply all over the internet for a solution.  Thanks.   ver 3.9.1 has an issue with gulp-regsiter.

Comment: This didn't help me :( 

C:\IntelliJWorkspace\productregistry>gulp -v
[12:22:53] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[12:22:53] CLI version 3.9.0
[12:22:53] Local version 3.9.0

Answer (score 3):

maybe this can help.

create `.babelrc` in your projects, and put this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many ways explaining above, including

```
npm install --global gulp
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

etc for installation of gulp, but finally found solution by running below command, which change gulp to something gulp-cli on phpStorm command line.

```
npm install -D babel
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

Answer (score 0):

me helped when i deleted and again installed both same version as global as local in the project directory the gulp and deleted and reinstal the babel-register.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall gulp
sudo npm install -g gulp@3.9.0
npm install gulp@3.9.0
npm uninstall babel-register
npm install babel-register
```